# Jquery data retrieving not work

Tags: jquery

I need to store the data to each 'li' element of my 'ul', in case if i assigning the value like this:

```
$('li:eq(0)').data('some', {name:'some',age:'some'})

$('li:eq(1)').data('some', {name:'some',age:'some'})
```

then is it correct. or any other short way to set the data to element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what exactly you're asking but, if you have some array/object with all values and want to set data for all LI elements, then you may want to use $.each().

example:

```
$("#yourUL").find("li").each(function() {
  // $(this) will stand for current LI element
  $(this).data('some', yourVarForThisLI);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) [iterates over](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/data.js#L305-311) each element in the jQuery set anyway, so you can just do;

```
$('li').data('some', { 
    name: 'some', 
    age: 'some' 
});
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain why?

Comment: this will work, if he needs to set **the same** data for all LI elements.